# Image file type verification in python

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to verify if my converted file has been converted correctly to a PGM file. When i try to verify using the usual pillow method of verification, my answer is PPM. Now the actual image file extension is pgm so I'm confused as to whether this is a pillow library assumption or if i have converted incorrectly. If anyone can help out that would be amazing, if i have converted incorrectly please feel free to suggest a new method, of conversion. In my current method i have simply saved the image as a .png and then converted it to pgm using the following pillow function

```
im = Image.open('test/test%d.png' % i)
im.save('test2/test%d.pgm' % i)
```

Comment: PGM image (image/x-portable-graym by the way in the properties of the image this is the Type

Comment: As a separate check, if you have the `file` command available (e.g. on Linux or Mac), you can use that to determine whether the content of the file looks like a PGM image, regardless of the filename or extension.

Comment: im sorry i dont mean to ask a stupid question but how would i do that on linux?

Comment: Same way you run any other command: in this case, at a shell prompt, `file name_of_file.pgm`. Or if you run `man file` it will give you plenty of information about the usage.